# Check if user is logged in

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-membership

I am using Microsoft visual basic 2010 for a asp.net site using c#.

I am using the asp.net configuration for user registration.  I have a comments form which I want to appear only if a user is logged in.

I now there is a toolbox helper thing called Login View which does exactly what I want but as soon as I put a form inside the code won't compile because it cannot find the textbox fields.

I have the following in NewsArticle.aspx:

```
<asp:LoginView ID="LoginView1" runat="server">
<AnonymousTemplate>
      <div class="postcomment">
           <p><a href="/account/Login.aspx">Login</a> or <a href="/account/Register.aspx">register</a> to post a comment.</p>
      </div>
 </AnonymousTemplate>
 <LoggedInTemplate>
      <div class="formcomment">
          <asp:TextBox ID="txtTitle" textMode="SingleLine" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
          <asp:TextBox ID="txtComment" TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
          <asp:Button ID="cmdUpdate" runat="server" Text="Add Comment" onclick="cmdUpdate_Click" />
      </div>
</LoggedInTemplate>
```

On the NewsArticle.aspx.cs I have:

```
protected void cmdUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    // Get user id
    Guid gUser;
    MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(Page.User.Identity.Name);
    gUser = (Guid)user.ProviderUserKey;

    // get article id
    int articleid = Convert.ToInt16(Request.QueryString["id"]);

    // Add to db
    FrontendTableAdapters.NewsCommentTableAdapter ta = new FrontendTableAdapters.NewsCommentTableAdapter();
    ta.Insert1(articleid, gUser.ToString(), txtTitle.Text, txtComment.Text);

    // Redirect back to article
    Response.Redirect(String.Format("NewsArticle.aspx?id={0}#comments", articleid));
}
```

If I take the form out of asp:LoginView it works fine.  Inside I get the following:

```
Error 2 The name 'txtTitle' does not exist in the current context NewsArticle.aspx.cs 59 53 Figmentville
Error 3 The name 'txtComment' does not exist in the current context \NewsArticle.aspx.cs 59 68 Figmentville
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot directly access txtTitle and txtComment.

These must be accessed through LoginView control since they are contained in it.

You should use FindControl method to locate these controls:
LoginView.FindControl( stringId)

Comment: Thanks for responding so quickly. I have tried the following:
ta.Insert1(articleid, gUser.ToString(), LoginView.FindControl(txtTitle).Text, oginView.FindControl(txtComment).Text);
but this still shows the same error :S.

Comment: Can you specify actual code and error messages. I believe it should be: LoginView1.FindControl("txtComment")
If this fails, the error message should be Nullreference exception.

Comment: I have the following:
LoginView1.FindControl(txtTitle).Text.
The error is:
Error 2 The name 'txtTitle' does not exist in the current context NewsArticle.aspx.cs 59 76 Figmentville

Comment: It should be within quotes: LoginView1.FindControl("txtTitle"). It will return you an object which you can cast to TextBox Control.